# Cannot compile my application after migrating to null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, console

In the debug mode, my application is being built but not in release mode as well `flutter build apk` is not working. The compiler is giving the following error in the console:

```
D:\All Data\Softwares\Latest Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\goog
lemaps\GoogleMapsPlugin.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.lifecycle.FlutterLifecycleAdapter;
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class FlutterLifecycleAdapter
  location: package io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.lifecycle
D:\All Data\Softwares\Latest Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\goog
lemaps\GoogleMapsPlugin.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
    lifecycle = FlutterLifecycleAdapter.getActivityLifecycle(binding);
                ^
  symbol:   variable FlutterLifecycleAdapter
  location: class GoogleMapsPlugin
Note: D:\All Data\Softwares\Latest Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugin
s\googlemaps\Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\All Data\Softwares\Latest Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugin
s\googlemaps\TileProviderController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_maps_flutter:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
```

So far what I have tried is:

- I had deleted the pubspec.lock file, ran flutter clean and then again flutter pub get. But that didn't helped.
- The error was being shown in GoogleMapsPlugin.java. I edited this file where it showed red line by removing, but that didn't help as well.

**Note:** Application was being released completely fine before migrating to null safety.

Answer (score 0):

Close Android studio
Delete the .pubcache folder inside Flutter/flutter manually.
Note it's a hidden folder.

Then do flutter clean and flutter pub get and flutter run. It should work.

Comment: Now facing the following error: `C:\Users\Bilal Saeed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.8.4+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePick
erPlugin.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.lifecycle.FlutterLifecycleAdapter;
`

Comment: Delete contents of that folder also. Flutter will rebuild it when needed.

Comment: Not working. Again facing the same error: `C:\Users\Bilal Saeed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\GoogleMapsPlugin.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
    lifecycle = FlutterLifecycleAdapter.getActivityLifecycle(binding);` . Went to this directory and deleted that. But still facing same error from GoogleMapsPlugin.java.

Comment: Did you try invalidate cache and restart of Android studio?

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well... But its not working either